# Javascript IF statement. ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference if any between;

```
if (removeIndex >= 0) {
      this.tasks.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    }
```

and

```
~removeIndex && this.tasks.splice(removeIndex, 1);
```

I understand the tilde(~) part as the not operator but the double && is confusing me. Are they doing exactly the same thing or not?

Comment: Let's start by saying that the bitwise not operator `~` just flips the bits, ex will turn a 5 into -6, which is completely different, so no they are not doing the same thing

Comment: To elaborate a bit on that. Every number is a truthy value except for `0`. By using `~removeIndex` you flip `-1` to `0` and vice versa, making it so that `-1` becomes a falsy value and `0` a truthy value.